# Windows Phone Application Bar Instance Remaining Same When Back Key Pressed

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I Have Created an application bar in the First Page and when a click occurs, it navigates to the Second Page and creates a new Application Bar in CodeBehind c#.

Till here it is Working fine but when i press the Back Hard Button while on the second page, the application bar instance is still remaining and appearing in first page.

In the `ONNAVIGATEDTO` method i'm making the instance of the first page appbar as `null` but it is not working and the  previous application bar (of the Second Page) is still showing in the firstPage.

Comment: Get rid of the code-behind app bar creation and declare it in XAML. Is there a reason to do it this way?

Comment: As Per My reqiruement i should Define the application Bar in code Behind because i should handle Application Bar According to anvigation from different pages for different page the application bar changes according to navigation flow.

Comment: Can you show some code reproducing the issue? Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

The application bar is different for each page. No need to create it in code behind.
The null assignment does not work because the appbar is not rendered yet. If you insist of doing it in code behind, which is not recommended, do it on page load. There is also an `Items.Clear()` method you can use to remove the app bar items. You should do it in XAML though.

Comment: My ApplicationBar should be defined According to Navigation. for Example consider 3 Pages if I come From firstpage to 2nd Page one Type of application bar contains some buttons if i come from 3rd page to 2nd page another type of application bar so in code behind i'm differinciating the Application Bar so thats way i'm defining application bar in c#.... @Pantelis

Comment: Alright, thats a better explanation of your problem. Use the ApplicationBar.Items.Clear() on page load event. Then depending on a querystring or any mechanism you use to identify from which page you have navigated from, populate the application bar with the items you have created in code behind with ApplicationBar.Items.Add().

Comment: I have Tried to clear the items but no use when i press the back key this was occuring...

Comment: Are you doing it on page load event?